# How to implement dynamic page curl in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, page-curl

I have implement the page curl in android by using the Github code of [android_page_curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/)

- Its working fine for me for only static pages.
- In this example taken images from drawable folder and done the page curl.

But my requirement is i want to implement page curl for dynamic pages.

I want exactly like this Video [Click here for video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP_AlvJqSLQ)

Is this option is possible in android,If possible give me some suggestions or links how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for you.

1. Each time when content on your page has changed - generate a static page from it and reinit your page curl view with a new content(consider using [getDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache(boolean))).
2. Write your own page curl lib for it.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer please.i didn't understand what you said.

Comment: i want to overwrite drawable option,instead of drawable i want to use layout in that link,is it possbile?

Comment: @User just call on view you want to draw getDrawingCache(), it returns you a bitmap then you need to create new BitmapDrawable(bitmap) - now you have drawable of view you want to display.

Comment: are you seen the link above,in this link there are using static drawable images,now i want instead of using static drawable images,i want to call layout pages.

Comment: can you give me some links for that.

Comment: @User i have no links. Method i described(1) works for "layout pages"

Comment: Stepango you attached wrong link,check oncegetDrawingCache()) it redirect to another page.

Comment: @User sorry for it, i changed link to valid

Comment: i didn't understand what getDrawablecache() is.

Comment: @User please read official documentation first to understand how getDrawableCache works. I already described how you could use it to solve your problem.

Comment: i have updated my question.can you verify that video once,and i want exactly like that.

Comment: @User i checked the video. If you'll do like i described - you'll see animations exacly like on video.